# Is $x^2$ always congruent to $(y-x)^2$ modulo $y$? How could you prove the cases where its true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've came across a problem recently which I've been thinking about, and am not sure if I am correct.

**Is $x^2$ always congruent to $(y-x)^2$ modulo $y$? Note: $y$ and $x$ are any integers.**

Since $y$ and $x$ are integers, can we say that $(y-x)^2 \le y$? Then, $(y-x)^2$ modulo $y$ $= (y-x)^2 \ne x^2$?

This is probably wrong. If it is, what's the proper way to approach this question? Is there any specific cases where it would be true?

Comment: You certainly can not say $(y - x)^2 \le y$. Consider $x = 0, y = 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of congruence modulo $n$ is: $a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $n$ if $n$ divides evenly into $a-b$.

Expand out $(y-x)^2-x^2$ to get $y^2-2xy+x^2-x^2 = y^2-2xy = y(y-2x)$. Notice that $y$ divides the result.

The definition of congruence that you are probably more familiar with is that of "reducing" a number modulo $n$, and we say $a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $n$ when "$a$ mod $n$ = $b$ mod $n$". This definition is equivalent, and typically works well for computer programming purposes, but it's not as conducive to proving results about congruence.

Comment: that should be $-2xy$ in the expansion, luckily it doesn't change the conclusion.

Comment: oh thanks for pointing that out! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because their difference $(y-x)^2-x^2=y^2-2xy$ is divisible by $y$. To say that $a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $n$ is to say that $a-b$ is divisible by $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^2-(y-x)^2=(x-(y-x))(x+(y-x))=(2x-y)y$.

Comment: Gotta love how this got auto-flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can also say it this way: $y=0\mod y$, thus $(y-x)^2=(0-x)^2=(-x)^2=x^2\mod y$.